# HIVE- Divide single row in to multiple rows

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have to prepare the query from source table to target table. table structure are shown in the image. Can any  one help on this.https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnUuZ.png
[Tables image]

Answer (score 0):

Hive's [stack](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF)) function should work here.

```
SELECT stack(2,
  col1, col2, col3, '',
  col1, col2, '', col4
) AS (newCol1, newCol2, newCol3, newCol4)
FROM source;
```

Basically, `stack` generates N rows for each row in the source, and you define each of these new rows.